# Broadcasting message over UDP C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming, udp

I'm having communication problems with my Program.cs class and my handleClinet.cs class.. Program handles accepting connection from every new client that attempts connecting, and handleClinet is responsible for handling every client's individual interaction.

I have a while loop in each class which is, i assume, where the problem lies.. but I'm not sure how else to do this. The server responses are not corresponding to what they're supposed to be responding. (i.e. not going into my broadcast function and executing the statements in the Program while loop) does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks in advance

```
class Program
{
    public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UdpClient server = new UdpClient(8888);
        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        string data = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Auction Server Started ....");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Reads data
                byte[] inStream = server.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                Console.WriteLine("REGISTER Client at " + remoteEndPoint);
                byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REGISTERED " + remoteEndPoint.ToString());
                server.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                clientsList.Add(data, server);
                client.startClient(server, data, clientsList, remoteEndPoint);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Broadcast method is used to send message to ALL clients
    public static void broadcast(UdpClient dest, string msg, string uName, bool flag, IPEndPoint sendEP)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
        {
            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

            if (flag == true)
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            }
            dest.Send(broadcastBytes, broadcastBytes.Length, sendEP);

        }
    }
}//end Main class
```

}

```
public class handleClinet
{
    UdpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    Hashtable clientsList;
    IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    IPEndPoint myEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    public void startClient(UdpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList, IPEndPoint tempEP)
    {
        this.myEP = tempEP;
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        this.clientsList = cList;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }

    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                byte[] received = clientSocket.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPoint);
                dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
                Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient);
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                if (dataFromClient.Contains("DEREGISTER"))
                    Program.broadcast(clientSocket, "DREG-CONF", clNo, true, myEP);
                else
                    Program.broadcast(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clNo, true, myEP);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                break;
            }
        }//end while
    }//end doChat
} //end class handleClinet
```

}

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that performs any sort of ACK on messages sent, i.e. which supports reliability over UDP. Are you aware that UDP is _unreliable_? For any datagram sent: it may or may not be delivered; if it is delivered, it may be delivered more than once; and it may or may not arrive in the same order relative to other datagrams in which it was sent. Your code appears to not concern itself with any of these issues.

Comment: I am aware of this, i had everything setup with TCP and it worked perfectly fine but i had missed the line in my assignment which stated i had to use UDP so i reformatted my code to work with UDP and now i'm having this problem. Is there any way to detect multiple receiving or lack of receive? Does the problem lie in the fact that i have 2 `while` loops?

Comment: Or is there a way to only execute the code in the while loop when a client requests to connect? @PeterDuniho

Comment: It could be an issue that you have two receiving loops, yes. It looks like both loops are reading from the same socket, so you have no control over which message is received in which loop. I haven't looked that closely at the code, but it also seems like you never actually set `UdpClient.EnableBroadcast`, so I'm a little confused about what you mean when you write "broadcast" in your question and comments. A couple of options are: dedicate a different `UdpClient` to initial connection and subsequent transactions; have a single receive loop and handle messages differently depending on contents.